# Get urls of the current tab and workaround for internal Chrome urls

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension i get an url of the current tab with `let newUrl = new URL(tab.url);`. But, if located on the Chrome internal urls, beginning with `chrome://` an extension throws an error `Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL`.

In the console an error looks as on screenshot:

[image]

The corresponding code is:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.url) run(tab);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(info => {
  chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, run);
});

const processingTabId = {};

function run(tab) {
  if (processingTabId[tab.id]) return;
  processingTabId[tab.id] = true;

  let newUrl = new URL(tab.url);
```

As even realized, the error throws always if i click on any link in the Google search results.

How to workaround this to work with `real` urls and don't get an error on `chrome://`-urls?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, `new URL` works with chrome:// URLs just fine. What is the actual value of `tab.url`?

Comment: It could be a real url with http/https protocol, and it can be an internal chrome url, beginning with `chrome://` - on internal urls a get an error - like on screenshot above.

Comment: No, your screenshot shows *where* the error occurred but I asked for the *value* of `tab.url`.

Comment: The most likely reason is that URL is not present at all, its value being `undefined`, which can happen if you get the active window's URL but the active window is devtools (it doesn't have tabs). Anyway, this is definitely not caused by chrome:// URLs. Debug your code properly, don't guess.

Comment: Got it! If i click on any link in the Google search results i get this error. Goes from code as above. It is maybe because Google uses a redirect?

Comment: Try `new URL(tab.pendingUrl || tab.url)`

Comment: as always from you, a mega tip :)